# Where are the docs of the [a..b] syntax for creating Lists in Elm?

Tags: list, elm

Where could I find the definition/documentation of the `[a..b]` syntax for creating Lists in Elm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax was removed in Elm 0.18. Use `List.range` instead. Some examples from `elm-repl`:

```
> List.range 1 5
[1,2,3,4,5] : List Int
> List.range 1 1
[1] : List Int
> List.range 1 0
[] : List Int
> List.range 1 5 |> List.map (\x -> x*2)
[2,4,6,8,10] : List Int
> List.range 1 5 |> List.map (\x -> x*2 - 1)
[1,3,5,7,9] : List Int
> let b = 5 in b |> List.range 1
[1,2,3,4,5] : List Int
```

*Note:* I have completely removed my previous answer because it was made obsolete by Elm 0.18.

Comment: I was hoping that something like `b |> (..) a` will be possible, but looks like `(..)` is not a function in Elm.

Comment: The closest you can do is `let a = 5 in [1..a]`.

Comment: Is this still a thing? I get an error when I try `map toString [1..24]` The error is `Cannot find variable ..`

Comment: Nope, it is no longer a thing. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Currently the only official documentation is the brief mention in the "Lists" section of the syntax reference: http://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax#lists